# How to tell pytest which folder to import from when multiple code versions are available?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest to test a code with a folder structure that is like this:

```
v1.1
 |__module1.py
 |__module2.py
v1.2
 |__module1.py
 |__module2.py
unit_tests
 |__test_module1.py
 |__test_module2.py
```

In `unit_tests`, each file contains unit tests for the methods contained in the corresponding module. I want to import the module from the desired version. What is the best way to do it? Can I specify it as an argument when running `python3 -m pytest test_moduleX.py` ?

I know that this is not the best versioning system but that's what I have to work with right now.